# octave install matlab package

Tags: matlab, octave

Recently I choose to use Octave instead of Matlab in Ubuntu12.04 due to the fact that it is open sourced. One problem I encounter is that when I try to install some additional package of matlab, it always fails.
For example, I want to install the randomforest matlab package (http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/), it needs to run command "make" to compile the c++ code etc. But first it tells me there's no mex command. To solve this, I modified the Makefile by replacing "mex" with "mkotfile --mex", after the second run, there are errors associated with the source code of the package.
This happens for multiple times, like I fails to install the libsvm in Octave.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Or I have to return to use Matlab.

Comment: You might want to have a look at a [previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178124/converting-matlab-files-to-octave) on that subject. There are some useful links there.

Answer (score 2):

Octave and Matlab are different enough to cause situations like these. Things developed for Matlab will usually not work as-is on Octave, especially external packages (i.e., not developed by the Mathworks).

You'll just have to persist -- re-write some parts of the code, install additional libraries here and there, etc. to get it to work.

It's always possible, but whether it's *practical*, that's for you to decide.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, maybe I have to return to Matlab or Numpy since modifying the code seems to be impractical for me.